# Union of two full graphs gives "Cannot add unknown type to igraph graph"

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to join two fully connected graphs in `igraph` to one graph via `union`. 
There are no edges between the two graphs (because I want to rewire them later)

However this code doesn't seem to work

```
g1 <-make_full_graph(10, directed = FALSE, loops = FALSE)
V(g1)$name <- c(1:10)

g2 <-make_full_graph(10, directed = FALSE, loops = FALSE)
V(g2)$name <- c(11:20)

u1 <- union(g1,g2)
```

I get the ERROR:

> "Error in `+.igraph`(g, setdiff(uninames, V(g)$name)) :
>     Cannot add unknown type to igraph graph"

Cane somebody clarify?

Comment: `V(g1)$name <- as.character(1:10)` etc

Comment: Thx! 
This fixes the problem with the union but I would generally prefer the data type to be integer. Is it possible with a name attribute in igraph?

Comment: No, names in R are generally characters.